# Should we ask to limit the number of Community bumped posts on the front page?

Tags: discussion, community

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped) about reasons for Community to bump questions notes that it's possible to impose a limit on how fast/often Community can bump posts:

> Some sites prevent additional questions from being auto-bumped while an auto-bumped question is near the top of the front page (i.e. the most recently active posts). If one of the top N posts, sorted by activity date, has been bumped, no questions will be auto-bumped by the Community user that hour.

It seems to me we might consider asking for that.  As I post this, Community is once again at 9/15 on the homepage.  (Not counting the recently-bumped question that collected a relatively poor-quality answer.)  9/15 is a lot; it's too much, and it's wiping out current activity.  And even once this flood abates, it's only going to re-occur in 120 days as the clock on all the currently-bumped posts times out and they become simultaneously eligible to bump again.

Comment: Ugh. Front page is being obliterated

Comment: It seems to have finally stopped doing all these bumps

Answer (score 11):

I think we should do this.  As I type up this answer Community is 13/15 on the home page and the site *really* looks dead.

[image: Top half of home page]

[image: Bottom half of home page]

Comment: On the plus side, we're getting to see which questions the zombie-bot upvoted. Usually it's total shit that should have been deleted almost immediately, but survived because it attracted an unwarranted upvote.

Comment: @Valorum I haven't been bothering to dig into all the bumped questions, but I do watch the Tools page.  So if there are any useless answers I can contribute a delete vote.

Comment: I'm generously estimating that about 1/2 of all the questions being bumped by the Community Bot have at least one answer that needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

*(Note: this answer expresses a personal opinion and not a mod decree. Feel free to downvote or post opposing answers if you disagree.)*

**I don't think this is necessary.**

The current situation is exceptional - it's not going to be every day, or even every year, that [tens of thousands of votes disappear due to a new suspicious vote detection tool being rolled out](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13956/31394). We need to weather the wave of Community bumps right now just as we need to weather the wave of lost reputation.

I don't know which sites have enabled limits on numbers of Community bumped posts, but I imagine most of them are very small sites. I've seen some sites on the SE network which have **so little activity** that the front page is always dominated by Community bumps, because nobody else is actually doing anything. That's not our case at all: SFF is a pretty active site, with many new questions and answers every day and many people editing posts all the time.

So, outside of exceptional circumstances like what's going on this week, I doubt we'll ever have a problem with Community bumping more than a few posts on the same day.

Comment: Does that mean I'm wrong to fear that Nov. 23 will see ~20 posts (those bumped today) all bumped again on the same day?

Comment: @DavidW I think so. I don't know exactly how the algorithm works, but experience suggests that bumps often happen when something changes (e.g. votes disappear), or maybe anniversaries of posts themselves, not just on anniversaries of previous bumps.

Comment: Ah, if it won’t happen the next go round then it’s fine to leave as is imo

Comment: As I type this, Community is at 12/15 on the front page.  You're sure this isn't a problem?

Comment: Hmm... How long is this wave exactly? All good if it doesn't happen again, but this _has_ been going on for some time

Comment: @Fez - There were tens of thousands of fake votes. Presumably there are tens of thousands of bumps coming.

Comment: @Valorum That's not how it works. You're assuming (?) that all of the robo-votes were cast specifically on zero-scoring answers to questions where no answer had a positive score.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The community bumps appear to be largely focused on low-scoring questions with a single low-scoring answer that would have been eligible for deletion if it hadn't attracted a single upvote.

Answer (score 2):

### Why not ask?

I personally think it wouldn't hurt to ask (The question is about asking).   The worst that could happen would be that SE agrees with @Randal'Thor and says "no".

But even in that case, we might also learn more about how the bumping algorithm works and be better prepared for the next time this happens.